# Restudding winter tires

Tags: tires

Alright so i know the pros and cons of doing it, and i promise you I've done a bit of research on the subject.

I have 4 "studded" winter tires that are beginning their 3rd season. I use quotes because only one of them has any studs left.
Ill be taking one of the remaining studs out so i can tell what size i need. I plan on purchasing the screw looking studs, mostly cus it looks tough trying to put in regular studs without a stud gun. 
I feel as though having the predesignated stud holes eliminates or reduces certain risks.

My main question, the only shred of information i couldn't obtain through Google is:

Does my tire need to be deflated before I put the studs in?

(I live in Alaska, man. I need muh studs!)

Comment: I would not use winter tires more than two winter seasons... and I’m in switzerland... the uv does the compound in...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I cannot tell you for sure, either. It seems to me when I was a kid (I grew up in Montana) and watching the tire guys putting studs in the tires, they were full of air. I can imagine the firmness of them helping with the insertion process (regular studs with a stud gun). However, with screw-in type studs, it is probably going to be far easier to screw them in with them deflated, then the tires will hold the studs better once re-inflated. LOL, and I bet the answer is "inflate to half pressure" :o)